# Symfony 4 - Error 11: Segmentation fault when starting server

Tags: php, symfony4

I was reading the setup page of symfony 4...

So I started creating my project by entering:

```
$ composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton relations
$ cd relations/
```

Then, I have launched the webserver by entering:

```
$ php bin/console server:run
```

But when accessing on localhost:8000, The server catch this error:

```
[ERROR] The process has been signaled with signal "11".
```

It's happen all time when I create a symfony project by using this command

```
composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton [name]
```

Anyone have an idea ?

Comment: That's a hot topic, go there  https://github.com/symfony/symfony/search?q=%5BERROR%5D+The+process+has+been+signaled+with+signal+%2211%22.&type=Issues to get the very last updates

Comment: @nicolallias thank's you ! 

    composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton=4.1.7.10 [name] 
work perfect

Comment: You are welcome! Since you managed to find the solution all by yourself, I just gave a hint ;)
You may consider add an answer to your question stating your findings and links that helped, wait for 3 days before "accepting" your own answer (that will facilitate research for others)

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue today.
This was happening because of a PHP 7.2 error.
Update it to the latest version and the error should be gone.

Comment: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/29341  TLDR: the new release of Symfony 4.1.8 found and triggered a bug in the OpCache module. A work-around has been done and a new version will likely be released soon.